# Calling a method on a dynamic object implementing a generic interface

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I've got a query object that's coming in off a service bus, deserialized from JSON - looks like it's working...

```
public TResult Execute<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query) where TResult : class {
....
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();            
var queryType = types.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name.Equals(message.MessageType));
var queryObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.Json, queryType, settings);
```

I then want to match it to the handler that's been registered for it's type (find the method that implements TResult IQueryHandler) - fine. The only constraint on TResult is that it's a class.

```
var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>);
var genericType = handlerType.MakeGenericType(new[] { queryType, typeof(TResult) });
var handler = (dynamic)Startup.SimpleInjector.Instance.GetInstance(genericType);
```

I then want to call the Handle method on this handler with the query object i've rebuilt, but that's where I'm getting:

```
result = handler.Handle(queryObj);
Log.Instance.Info("result {0}", result);

An exception occurred, MassTransit.Exceptions.RequestException: The response handler threw an exception ---> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'HomeApi.Handlers.Workflow.AnyWorkflowsStartWithEventQueryHandler.Handle(HomeApi.Queries.AnyWorkflowsStartWithEventQuery)' has some invalid arguments
```

I've verified that the handler is being returned from SimpleInjector (although would casting it to a dynamic cause a problem here?) and that the handler takes the query and returns the expected TResult so not sure why I'm getting this result. Any help appreciated.

here's the definition of IQueryHandler<,>

```
public interface IQueryHandler<T, out TR> where T : class where TR : class
{
    TR Handle(T query);
}
```

and IQuery:

```
public interface IQuery<T> where T : class
{
    string Type { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.Json, queryType, settings);` returns `object`, you'd want to actually call the `Handle` fuction with the real type, such as this:

```
result = handler.Handle((dynamic)queryObj);
```

Right now, you're calling `handler.Handle<MyRealType>(object)`.

Comment: Hi Chris,

The call to `DeserializeObject` results in a concrete query type implementing `IQuery (AnyWorkflowsStartWithEventQuery)`

Handler is returned from a SimpleInjector container of generic handlers to concrete `(AnyWorkFlowsStartWithEventQueryHandler which is IQueryHandler<AnyWorkflowsStartWithEventQuery, List<IWorkflow>>`

I think `TResult handler.Handle<IQuery, TResult>` is what I'm after but it doesn't seem to like what I'm trying to call Handle with. I can post the method if that'd help

Comment: Yeah I tried adding the dynamic cast to query obj, but unfortunately results in the same exception:

`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'HomeApi.Handlers.Workflow.AnyWorkflowsStartWithEventQueryHandler.Handle(HomeApi.Queries.AnyWorkflowsStartWithEventQuery)' has some invalid arguments at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )`

Comment: I've created a gist of the method here https://gist.github.com/danbyrne84/66698b6c438923708d2a

Comment: @managedheap84, it's hard to see what's going wrong. I suggest you to do things step by step. Can you be sure that `Startup.SimpleInjector.Instance.GetInstance` returns what it should return? Replace it with temporarily what you think is right. Dump each type/object and its method. There's no need to fight the error, there's a signature mismatch on what you're trying to call :-)